# Pandas: concatenate multilevel index such that the other Dataframe has different sorting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, multi-level

Consider you have the following two dataframes `dfs` and `df1`

dfs is defined by

```
dfs=pd.DataFrame({
    'Year':[2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006], 
    'Provider':list('abcsd'),
    'Accepted': [2570, 1020, 2140, 120, 15]
 }) 

dfs=dfs.groupby(['Year', 'Provider']).sum()
```

df1 is defined by

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    'Year':[2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006], 
    'Provider':list('aabbc'),
    'Gender': list('mfmfm'),
    'Accepted app': ['990', '1180', '435', '405', '985']
 })
```

I want to merge these two dataframes to get something like so

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'Year':[2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006,2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006], 
    'Provider':list('abcsdabcsd'),
    'Accepted': [2570, 1020, 2140, 120, 15,2570, 1020, 2140, 120, 15],
    'Gender': ['m', 'm', 'm', 'Nan', 'Nan', 'f', 'f', 'Nan', 'Nan', 'Nan'],
    'Accepted app': ['990', '435', '985', 'Nan', 'Nan','1180', '405', 'Nan', 'Nan', 'Nan']

 })
```

I do not know how to retain the multilevel index of `dfs` or how to merge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat rows by unique values of `Gender` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then `merge` with left join:

```
df = (pd.concat([dfs.assign(Gender=c) for c in df1['Gender'].unique()])
        .reset_index()
        .merge(df1, on=['Provider','Year','Gender'], how='left'))
print (df)
   Year Provider  Accepted Gender Accepted app
0  2006        a      2570      m          990
1  2006        b      1020      m          435
2  2006        c      2140      m          985
3  2006        d        15      m          NaN
4  2006        s       120      m          NaN
5  2006        a      2570      f         1180
6  2006        b      1020      f          405
7  2006        c      2140      f          NaN
8  2006        d        15      f          NaN
9  2006        s       120      f          NaN
```

If want also set `Gender` column to missing values is possible identify source of new rows by `indicator=True` parameter in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then replace by missing values:

```
df = (pd.concat([dfs.assign(Gender=c) for c in df1['Gender'].unique()])
        .reset_index()
        .merge(df1, on=['Provider','Year','Gender'], how='left', indicator=True)
        .assign(Gender=lambda x: x['Gender'].mask(x['_merge'].eq('left_only')))
        .drop('_merge', axis=1))

print (df)
   Year Provider  Accepted Gender Accepted app
0  2006        a      2570      m          990
1  2006        b      1020      m          435
2  2006        c      2140      m          985
3  2006        d        15    NaN          NaN
4  2006        s       120    NaN          NaN
5  2006        a      2570      f         1180
6  2006        b      1020      f          405
7  2006        c      2140    NaN          NaN
8  2006        d        15    NaN          NaN
9  2006        s       120    NaN          NaN
```